# Smart constructors on data class unsafe when using copy: how to avoid that?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

In the [doc about Validation, when speaking of Smart constructor](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/validation/#smart-constructors), it's suggested to use them on data class, but making this possible:

```
object EmptyAuthorName

data class Author private constructor(val name: String) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(name: String): Either<EmptyAuthorName, Author> = either {
            ensure(name.isNotEmpty()) { EmptyAuthorName }
            Author(name)
        }
    }
}

Author("fo")
    .map { it.copy(name = "") }
    .run { println(this) } // Either.Right(Author(name=))
```

The EmptyAuthorName constraint wasn't respected. Really bad isn't it?

Redefining copy for the data class isn't possible...

Currently my only way out is to not use data class.

Am i missing something?

Comment: You are not missing something. The tutorial is only about writing a smart *constructor*. It's not about writing a smart `copy`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term ‘smart constructor’.  From this example, it seems to be, not a constructor at all, but a **factory method**.  Maybe the inaccurate name is the source of some confusion?

Answer (score 2):

The primary constructor of a data class is *always* available via the copy method. You either have to make sure that the result of the primary constructor is valid, or you must not use a data class.

In this case, the validation logic seems to be in a wrapper around the data class, not in the data class itself. That means you can do the validation on an instance of `Author`, instead of "faking" a constructor call. Then you can call it after operations like `map`, and you'll always get a properly validated `Either`.

```
data class Author(val name: String) {
        fun validate(): Either<EmptyAuthorName, Author> = either {
            ensure(name.isNotEmpty()) { EmptyAuthorName }
            this
        }
}

Author("fo").validate()
    .map { it.copy(name = "").validate() }
    .run { println(this) } // Either.Left(EmptyAuthorName)
```

Another upside of doing it this way is that your code becomes easier to understand. In your example, you have a function that looks like an `Author` constructor, but it doesn't return an instance of `Author` (but an instance of `Either`). That's confusing. Making a function that clearly specifies that it validates and returns a validated result is better and easier to understand.

Comment: thx a lot @Jorn  

One would now need to call validate() to check the instance is correct, leading to potentially invalid instances, which is what i wanted to avoid in the first place :/   

Also the smart constructor pattern isn't mine, but from Kotlin Arrow: https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/validation/#smart-constructors -> i would expect it to be "ok" for kotlin arrow users no?

Comment: I have no experience with Arrow. Perhaps the "smart constructor" pattern is not meant for data classes? Or perhaps you are simply expected not to call `copy`?

Comment: ... or, after reading the docs, perhaps this is just an oversight in the library. Do note that there is *always* an indication whether you have a raw `Author` or a validated one, even with "smart" constructors: The former is typed `Author`, the latter is typed `Either<*,Author>`.